# What happens if a PMT (photmultiplier tube) is run below its operating voltage?

Tags: radiation, voltage, electronics, photoelectric-effect, nuclear-engineering

I have this Hamamatsu PMT that says its operating voltage is 1500 V. However, it has serious electronic/background noise at LLD=0 at that operating voltage. If I lower it down to about 1.02 KV, noise is supressed by much. My question is, is it always necessary to run a PMT at its operating voltage? What happens when one runs it at a significantly lower bias, like 1000 V or 700 V? I feel like I swamp my detector a lot less using a lower voltage, but I'm not sure that it's correct to run a PMT at any voltage but its operating one.

Comment: Are you interested in discrete counts, or in the photocurrent and is dependence on other variables? If the latter, I'd worry about possible nonlinearities.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I'm interested in the total number of counts given a certain LLD, but at the operating voltage of 1500 V, I'm seeing a huge pulse (larger than the noise pulses) on the oscilloscope. I'm trying to figure out the lowest I can go without corrupting, if that can be possible, any counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can still see your signal, by all means use the lowest V that gives enough gain - but the gain is very sensitive to supply V

The photocurrent multiplication factor is a high power of the Volts applied to the tube

This also makes power supply noise an important consideration

https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/etd/PMT_handbook_v3aE.pdf

tldr:

http://www.bo.infn.it/ams/Hamamatsu-PMT.pdf

> Since photomultiplier tubes generally have 9 to 12 dynode
>   stages, the anode output varies directly with the 6th to 10th
>   power of the change in applied voltage. The output signal of the
>   photomultiplier tube is extremely susceptible to fluctuations in
>   the power supply voltage, thus the power supply must be very
>   stable and provide minimum ripple, drift and temperature coefficient.